# how to prevent theft of apikey?

Tags: web-services, api

When calling an API with an API key through js, what measures are generally taken to protect the API key from theft?  Making the call server-side would probably be more ideal for this scenario but what about scenarios where the API call needs to be made entirely through js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just cannot. If the API call is performed from a client (a web browser, for example) the user will be able to inspect the outgoing traffic and see the API key. In this case I can think of two workarounds:

- Make an AJAX request to your backend and perform the API call IN your backend. It could be slower because two http request would be performed, but the client would never have access to the secret API key.
- If you have control over the API backend, modify the authentication strategy to avoid using a single shared API key.

Comment: Couldn't the entire js file be obfuscated?  This would obfuscate everything including the API key

Comment: Your problem is not that someone could read your code. The problem is that even without reading your code, the web browser would execute the obfuscated code and perform a clear and easy HTTP request, readable by the user

Comment: was "clear and e" an iPhone autocorrect?